# redux container to connect multiple component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a list page and a create page, I have no problem doing the list page. The list page will have action, reducers and store, I've no problem with that. Now I'm stuck on how to connect one store to multiple component.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Ads from '../../components/admin/ads';
import createAd from '../../Components/admin/createAd' // how to connect this too?

//redux action
import { getAds } from '../../actions/admin/ads';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.adsReducer
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAds: () => {
        dispatch(getAds())
    }
  }
}

const AdsContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Ads)

export default AdsContainer;
```

It make no sense for a new page createAd to have its own container as it fall under ads category.

Comment: Firstly you need to decide of create ad is a pure component or one which renders only a view. If its a pure component then pass data from the container as props and render only a view.

Comment: @NitishPhanse it has ntg to do with pure or not pure component

Comment: Can you attach the render method too

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to connect the store to an `<App>` component which sits above both the List and Create components ---  then you can pass the data down to each.

Fundamentally, if you want `<ComponentB>` to get data provided by a `connect(...)(ComponentA)` call, then `<ComponentB>` needs to be a child of `<ComponentA>`.  That's just regular React, data flows down the tree.  If you want it to flow to a different part of the tree, move the data higher.

Comment: assume componentA is a list page, componentB is a form, why a form is a child of a list? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree, that doesn't make sense.  That's why you instead might want a different component which is a parent of them both.  Say that you want the form to display above your list.  Then you might want: